# Getting specific field from chosen Row in Pyspark DataFrame

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark DataFrame built through *pyspark* from a JSON file as

```
sc = SparkContext()
sqlc = SQLContext(sc)

users_df = sqlc.read.json('users.json')
```

Now, I want to access a *chosen_user* data, where this is its _id field. I can do

```
print users_df[users_df._id == chosen_user].show()
```

and this gives me the full Row of the user. But suppose I just want one specific field in the Row, say the user gender, how would I obtain it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just filter and select:

```
result = users_df.where(users_df._id == chosen_user).select("gender")
```

or with `col`

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

result = users_df.where(col("_id") == chosen_user).select(col("gender"))
```

Finally PySpark `Row` is just a `tuple` with some extensions so you can for example `flatMap`:

```
result.rdd.flatMap(list).first()
```

or `map` with something like this:

```
result.rdd.map(lambda x: x.gender).first()
```